# How to update mysql with current date with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a MySQL table with current date into a column which type is DATE. current date structure is (2014-05-15). I've tried a few ways but it is not updating the date, however it is updating other fields.

MySQL query.

```
$q = "UPDATE TABLE SET
    DESCRIPTION     =".$db->qstr($string).",
        DATE        =".$db->qstr(date('Y-m-d')).",
    LAST_ACT        =".$db->qstr( time())."
    WHERE  ID=".$db->qstr( $id);
```

I've tried DATE = DATE(NOW()), and DATE = DATE(), but it is not updating in MySQL,

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only date is not updating or the whole update query fails? And what does `$db->qstr` do? You'll also need quotes around your variables if they datatype is string.

Comment: only date is not updating. others update fine

Comment: What is the dataype of `DATE` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of DATE = DATE(NOW()). 
Try DATE = NOW()

Comment: I feel stupid to say but it was working all along, I was updating another database. Thanks everyone and sorry about my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try DATE=CURDATE() which will return a date data type. If that doesn't work, try doing some trial and error directly in the database console to see what works and what responses you get. And be sure and update us on the results.

Comment: In the code you posted there are no quotes around the right operands for your string and date types. I'm not sure how the description is being properly saved, but try this for date: DATE        ='".$db->qstr(date('Y-m-d'))."',

Comment: Or ... DATE=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Thanks chad, all solutions worked!. see my reply above. sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
Use now() function for it.

So it will be :

DATE = now()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it was working all along. guess I got to double up on my coffee. I was updating a different table